# performance issue when import reactor module before os.fork()

Tags: python, performance, twisted

i got a performance issue when trying to do:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
#some codes here
pid = os.fork()
if not pid:
    #some codes blahblahblah
    reactor.run()
```

this caused very low performance and i didn't find useful informations from the official documentation, i believe it because i import reactor module before os.fork(), any idea?

Comment: While I could answer that you probably shouldn't be doing this, I'm curious about what performance you're talking about.  What would make this a much better question is if you create a complete, runnable example which demonstrates the performance degradation you're observing.  As things are now, any answer is going to be a pretty wild guess, because no one knows what your program does, nor what performance you're measuring.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will organize codes and post it later
the basic idea for now is i doubt the parent and child process are shareing some same fds and os have some locks on that.
for parent process, it holds fd:
8 -> pipe:[280311]
9 -> pipe:[280311]
for child process, it's the same:
8 -> pipe:[280311]
9 -> pipe:[280311]
i don't know what's the pipe used for.maybe for the Waker of reactor?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use subprocess instead of os.fork?

Comment: i don't want to break or replace the existing codes. For me, it's hard to estimate the risk